# Unable to load images into ImageView using Glide

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-glide

I am an iOS developer and fairly new to Kotlin/Android so I'm a bit lost and confused.

I have a ViewPager in a fragment that needs to load an image from a url for each item in the pager. Each item in the pager is an instance of a pager fragment. I am using `Glide` to load images. The code I am using to render the images was taken from an activity class where is works without issue. However, in the pager fragment, no images load.

Here is my layout file for the pager item fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="some.path.StatCardPagerItem">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/statCardImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

In my fragment I have the following in `onCreateView`:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_pager_item, container, false)
    val imgView = view.statCardImageView

    card?.url?.let {
        GlideApp.with(imgView.context)
            .load(card?.url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_avatar)
            .into(imgView)
    }
    return view
}
```

When the pager loads, the correct number of pager items is displayed, but they only contain the placeholder avatars. The confusing part is that the code to load the images from Glide works if contained in an Activity but not in the fragment. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: If you place a breakpoint inside your "let" code, does it get hit?
I would also suggest trying removing the .context from imgView.context

Comment: @RodrigoE. Yes, there is a valid non-null url and the Glide code block is getting hit

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the ImageView context. As per Glide documentation, you should pass the Fragment instance into the `with` method.

Try with:

```
GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(card?.url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_avatar)
            .into(imgView)
```

Reference: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#with-android.app.Fragment-

> public static RequestManager with(View view)
>
> Begin a load with Glide
>   that will be tied to the lifecycle of the Fragment, Fragment, or
>   Activity that contains the View. A Fragment or Fragment is assumed to
>   contain a View if the View is a child of the View returned by the
>   Fragment.getView()} method.
>
> This method will not work if the View is
>   not attached. Prefer the Activity and Fragment variants unless you're
>   loading in a View subclass.
>
> This method may be inefficient for large hierarchies. Consider
>   memoizing the result after the View is attached.

Comment: I've tried the fragment context and about every other context I can think to try, but nothing works

Comment: The correct way of using Glide in most of the cases is to pass `this` to the `with` method. If that solution is not working, I would ensure the Glide code is executed and if it is, that the `load` argument has a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an activity context in `with()` method

```
GlideApp.with(getActivity())
        .load(card?.url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_avatar)
        .into(imgView)
```

Answer (score 0):

to load images into `ImageView` using `Glide`

```
Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView)
```